# Thunderbird is checking mail periodically, even this feature is turned off

Tags: email, thunderbird, email-client

I use thunderbird very heavily many years, updating the app, keeping the profile dir for years. The problem is, on any account, even new, I uncheck all checkboxes, especially "Check on startup" and "Check periodically".

But anyway I receive notifications about new mail on these accounts. If I check "Automatically download new messages", they are also automatically downloaded, without "Check periodically" checkboxes. How to disable it? Why it is checking all accounts? I looked into all settings and never found the reason.
Only FireTray is used from addons. Please help

The problem was on all versions I used. Before 45 series, now 52.0

Comment: Are you using POP or IMAP? I suspect you are using IMAP and then this is perfectly normal. The send/receive is meant for the POP protocol, because with IMAP you always work on the server.

Comment: I use both, but the problem mostly occurs with POP accounts, which is very strange. No IDLE support, but anyway it checks it.